# JavaScript - Onclick function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to call the function on button click. Function itself works fine (i can log it), but I cannot display it in the browser on button click. I am doing in for the first time and the problem should be pretty obvious for Experienced JS programer.

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>X</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pickButton">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="CLICK HERE TO PICK NOW!" onclick="giveNumbers()">
    </div>

    <div class="mainNumberSpanAndTitle">
        <label>MAIN NUMBERS: </label>
            <span id="mainNumberSpan"></span>
    </div>
<script>

 function giveNumbers() {

   var digits = []
   for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
       var digit = getRandomNumber1to50()  
       digits.push(digit)
   }
   digits.push(getRanomNumber1to7())
   digits.push(getRanomNumber1to7())
   return digits


 }

function getRandomNumber1to50() {
  var num;
  num = Math.random()*50+1;
  num = Math.floor(num);  
  return num
}

function getRanomNumber1to7() {
  var num;
  num = Math.random()*7+1;
  num = Math.floor(num);  
  return num
}
    var mainNumberSpan = document.getElementById('mainNumberSpan');

    mainNumberSpan.innerHTML = digits;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue ?

Comment: There's something odd in the curly braces. There should'n be double braces for the first function.

Comment: First of all, maybe a typo, but you put two curly braces in the `giveNumbers` declaration. Then, this function returns an array, which itself won't do anything, what do you want to do with these numbers ?

Comment: Nothing happens when I click the button.

Comment: I just want to display 8 random numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one
you use `innerHTML` outside the `giveNumbers` function so you change set value for `span` in `giveNumbers` function and no require `return` from this function

```js
function giveNumbers() {

  var digits = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    var digit = getRandomNumber1to50();
    digits.push(digit);
  }
  digits.push(getRanomNumber1to7());
  digits.push(getRanomNumber1to7());

  var mainNumberSpan = document.getElementById('mainNumberSpan');
  mainNumberSpan.innerHTML = digits;
}

function getRandomNumber1to50() {
  var num;
  num = Math.random() * 50 + 1;
  num = Math.floor(num);

  return num
}

function getRanomNumber1to7() {
  var num;
  num = Math.random() * 7 + 1;
  num = Math.floor(num);

  return num
}
```

```html
<div id="pickButton">
  <input class="button" type="button" value="CLICK HERE TO PICK NOW!" onclick="giveNumbers()">
</div>

<div class="mainNumberSpanAndTitle">
  <label>MAIN NUMBERS: </label>
  <span id="mainNumberSpan"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `document.write(digit)` to display 
but rather you can use innerHtml to display in any tag its batter than document.write()

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>X</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pickButton">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="CLICK HERE TO PICK NOW!" onclick="giveNumbers()">
    </div>

    <div class="mainNumberSpanAndTitle">
        <label>MAIN NUMBERS: </label>
            <span id="mainNumberSpan"></span>
    </div>
<script>

 function giveNumbers() {{

   var digits = []
   for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
       var digit = getRandomNumber1to50()  
       digits.push(digit)
   }
   digits.push(getRanomNumber1to7())
   digits.push(getRanomNumber1to7())
   document.write(digits);


 }

function getRandomNumber1to50() {
  var num;
  num = Math.random()*50+1;
  num = Math.floor(num);  
  return num
}

function getRanomNumber1to7() {
  var num;
  num = Math.random()*7+1;
  num = Math.floor(num);  
  return num
}
    var mainNumberSpan = document.getElementById('mainNumberSpan');

    mainNumberSpan.innerHTML = digits;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i know thats y i told to use innerHtml

Answer (score 0):

```js
function giveNumbers() {

  var digits = []
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    var digit = getRandomNumber1to50()
    digits.push(digit)
  }
  digits.push(getRanomNumber1to7())
  digits.push(getRanomNumber1to7())

  document.getElementById('mainNumberSpan');

  mainNumberSpan.innerHTML = digits;


}

function getRandomNumber1to50() {
  var num;
  num = Math.random() * 50 + 1;
  num = Math.floor(num);
  return num
}

function getRanomNumber1to7() {
  var num;
  num = Math.random() * 7 + 1;
  num = Math.floor(num);
  return num
}
```

```html
<div id="pickButton">
  <input class="button" type="button" value="CLICK HERE TO PICK NOW!" onClick="giveNumbers()">
</div>

<div class="mainNumberSpanAndTitle">
  <label>MAIN NUMBERS: </label>
  <span id="mainNumberSpan"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad it help you. Accept answer for few minutes, when you will able to.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this online example .

If you put something intro { .namespace for JS. } 
You will need to make call for executing .

```js
 

 function giveNumbers() {
   var digits = []
   for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
       var digit = getRandomNumber1to50()  
       digits.push(digit)
   }
   digits.push(getRanomNumber1to7())
   digits.push(getRanomNumber1to7())
    alert("trigger")
    var mainNumberSpan = document.getElementById('mainNumberSpan');

    mainNumberSpan.innerHTML = digits;
    
   return digits
 }

function getRandomNumber1to50() {
  var num;
  num = Math.random()*50+1;
  num = Math.floor(num);  
  return num
}

function getRanomNumber1to7() {
  var num;
  num = Math.random()*7+1;
  num = Math.floor(num);  
  return num
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>X</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pickButton">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="CLICK HERE TO PICK NOW!" onclick="giveNumbers()">
    </div>

    <div class="mainNumberSpanAndTitle">
        <label>MAIN NUMBERS: </label>
            <span id="mainNumberSpan"></span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here Some mistakes in your code.

2 `{{ }}` should be single  `{}` in `giveNumbers()`

Hope this will helps you

```js
function giveNumbers() {
   var digits = []
   for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
       var digit = getRandomNumber1to50()  
       digits.push(digit)
   }
   digits.push(getRanomNumber1to7())
   digits.push(getRanomNumber1to7())
   var mainNumberSpan = document.getElementById('mainNumberSpan');
   mainNumberSpan.innerHTML = digits;
 }

function getRandomNumber1to50() {
  var num;
  num = Math.random()*50+1;
  num = Math.floor(num);  
  return num
}

function getRanomNumber1to7() {
  var num;
  num = Math.random()*7+1;
  num = Math.floor(num);  
  return num
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>X</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pickButton">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="CLICK HERE TO PICK NOW!" onclick="giveNumbers()">
    </div>

    <div class="mainNumberSpanAndTitle">
        <label>MAIN NUMBERS: </label>
            <span id="mainNumberSpan"></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>X</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pickButton">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="CLICK HERE TO PICK NOW!" onclick="giveNumbers()">
    </div>

    <div class="mainNumberSpanAndTitle">
        <label>MAIN NUMBERS: </label>
            <span id="mainNumberSpan"></span>
    </div>
<script>

 function giveNumbers() {

   var digits = []
   for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
       var digit = getRandomNumber1to50()  
       digits.push(digit)
   }
   digits.push(getRanomNumber1to7())
   digits.push(getRanomNumber1to7())
   //return digits; // Remove it 

function getRandomNumber1to50() {
  var num;
  num = Math.random()*50+1;
  num = Math.floor(num);  
  return num
}

function getRanomNumber1to7() {
  var num;
  num = Math.random()*7+1;
  num = Math.floor(num);  
  return num
}
    var mainNumberSpan = document.getElementById('mainNumberSpan');

    mainNumberSpan.innerHTML = digits;
    console.log(mainNumberSpan);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change function to this:

```
function giveNumbers() {{
   var digits = []
   for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
       var digit = getRandomNumber1to50()  
       digits.push(digit)
   }
   digits.push(getRanomNumber1to7())
   digits.push(getRanomNumber1to7())
   var mainNumberSpan = document.getElementById('mainNumberSpan'); // added these
   mainNumberSpan.innerHTML = digits; 
 }
```